# Rails 5: How to pass attributes of a parent resource to a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, `MultipleChoiceQuestion` that has five attributes: `answer_one`, `answer_two`, `answer_three`, `answer_four` and `answer_five`, along with a field called `answer_correct`

I want to track what each user picks **onClick** after they load each question. Probably using remote: true - I've been reading on the internet and it seem that creating a nested polymorphic model called `UserAnswer` would be a smart thing to do, to track the user's answer selection per question.

However, what I'm confused about is how I would pass the parameters of the original model (MultipleChoiceQuestion) to the new model in the view, as my understanding is that all models have different attributes in the database. (How would I make sure i can persist what the user picked with their click through a secondary model, when the information strings come from the parent model?)

Is it possible to pass attributes of parent model to a nested one? The purpose here is to let users see what they got right or wrong over time.

**MultipleChoiceQuestion.rb Model**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: multiple_choice_questions
#
#  id                                         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  question                                   :text
#  answer_one                                 :text
#  answer_two                                 :text
#  answer_three                               :text
#  answer_four                                :text
#  answer_correct                             :text
#  answer_explanation                         :text
#  published                                  :boolean
#  flagged                                    :boolean
#  user_id                                    :bigint(8)
#  created_at                                 :datetime         not null
#  updated_at                                 :datetime         not null
#  slug                                       :string           not null
#  source                                     :string
#  reviewed                                   :boolean
#  who_reviewed                               :string
#  reviewed_at                                :datetime
#  difficulty_rating                          :integer
#  multiple_choice_question_classification_id :integer
#  controversial                              :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  origination                                :integer          default("not_given")

Class MultipleChoiceQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  validates :user, presence: true

  belongs_to :multiple_choice_question_classification, optional: true

  has_many :flags, dependent: :destroy

  acts_as_taggable

  # activity feed
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: Proc.new { |controller, model| controller.current_user ? controller.current_user : nil }

  validates :question, :slug, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates_uniqueness_of :question
```

User.rb model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  email                  :string           default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string           default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token   :string
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0), not null
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#  first_name             :string
#  last_name              :string
#  school_name            :string
#  graduation_year        :string
#  current_sign_in_token  :string
#  admin                  :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  superadmin             :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  verified               :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  premiumuser            :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  regularuser            :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  banneduser             :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  user_role              :boolean          default(TRUE)
#  username               :string           default(""), not null
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :multiple_choice_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :flags
  has_many :saved_items

  has_one_attached :avatar
```

View - multiple_choice_questions/show.html.erb

```
<h5>
    <%= @multiple_choice_question.question %>
  </h5>

  <p>
    <span>Answer choice #1:</span>
    <%= @multiple_choice_question.answer_one %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <span>Answer choice #2:</span>
    <%= @multiple_choice_question.answer_two %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <span>Answer choice #3:</span>
    <%= @multiple_choice_question.answer_three %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <span>Answer choice #4:</span>
    <%= @multiple_choice_question.answer_four %>
  </p>

  <p class="correct">
    <span>Correct Answer:</span>
    <%= @multiple_choice_question.answer_correct %>
  </p>
```

Comment: have you tried delegate? https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Comment: @MahmoudSayed I don't see how that would work, as the attributes are directly set on the model I want to inherit from

Comment: You could always attach a javascript listener to each of your answers and have the event grab the ID of the answer and post that answer to your UserAnswers controller which at that point would save the answer associated with the user that is also associated with the question. You could also just handle the logic within your MultipleChoiceQuestion model to create UserAnswers based off of the selected answer if you don't want to mess with Javascript.

Comment: How can you handle logic within the parent (MultipleChoiceQuestion) model? I haven't created a UserAnswer model yet, as i put answer choices 1-5 in the parent model.

Comment: What is the datatype of `answer_correct`?

Comment: Also how you will track answer of a particular question? Do you have `Question` model?

Comment: @Pavan answer_correct is 'text', not string. Also, no - there is just a parent model called MultipleChoiceQuestion that has answer_one through five, and there is also a correct_answer attribute for this parent model.

Comment: So the `answer_correct` stores the correct answer for the question, right?

Comment: Do you have User model? If so update the question with the both models

Comment: I want to see the associations of the models. Also post the code of the view where you have listing questions to the user.

Comment: @Pavan Updated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to stay with your current schema architecture, then you may require the below steps to achieve what you need

**Steps:** (code snippets are updated as per the discussion with the OP)

1) Define a **custom route** which you can use it in the *AJAX* to send the user selected answer and receive the result.

```
#routes.rb
post '/verify_user_selected_answer', to: "multiple_choice_questions#verify_user_selected_answer'
```

2) Have the answers as *links* for the user to click on like so

```
<%= link_to @multiple_choice_question.answer_one, "javascript:void(0);", class: "answer" %>
```

3) Trigger an *AJAX* call when the user clicks on the answer

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.answer").on( "click", function( event ) {
  var current_answer = $(this);
  var question_id = '<%= @multiple_choice_question.id %>';
  var current_user = "<%= current_user.id %>"; 

  $.ajax({
    url: "/verify_user_selected_answer",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {user_id: current_user, question: question_id, answer: current_answer.text()}, 
    success: function(response){
      $("#display_result").text(response["result"]); 
     }
  });
  });
});
```

4) Have a `div` to display the result.

`<div id="display_result">`

5) Finally in the `multiple_choice_questions#verify_user_selected_answer` perform the verification and send back the result

```
def verify_user_selected_answer
  @multiple_choice_question = MultipleChoiceQuestion.find(params[:question])
  @selected_answer = params[:answer]
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @multiple_choice_question.update_attribute(user_id, @user.id)

  if @selected_answer.downcase == @multiple_choice_question.answer_correct.downcase
    @result = "Correct answer!"
  else
    @result = "Wrong answer!"
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { result: @result } }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am assuming the model name here would be `SelectedAnswer`? I get this error in the console, and nothing happens when I click on the links in the view. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` and it refers  to this line particularly `success: function(response){` in the code you provided

Comment: @mazing can you provide a screenshot of that error? Also why you need another model for selected answer? If you want to store the user's selected answer, you can create a column in the `multiple_choice_questions` table and store the value to that column

Comment: The error is this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` https://imgur.com/a/KPvJTpP Would that allow me to see all the users different answer selections though? @Pavan

Comment: @mazing Ofcourse you need to save user id to `user_id` column as well which will map a user selected answer to that user in the `multiple_choice_questions` table

Comment: This is all I have, the rails console has no error, and nothing happens in the view when I click on a link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182140/discussion-between-pavan-and-mazing).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

First, you need to have some kind of reference to your exam or test. 
Second, your exam needs to have x number of questions. 
Third, you questions need to have x number of possible answers with one answer that is correct. Then, you take your user model and associate that user to tests and answers like this.

Please note this is not valid syntax but is for explanation purposes only.

```
class Exam has_many :questions
           has_and_belongs_to_many :users

class Question has_many :answers
               has_many :user_answers
               belongs_to :exam

class Answer belongs_to :question

class UserAnswer belongs_to :question
                 belongs_to :user

class User has_and_belongs_to_many :exams
           has_many :user_answes
```

Now, you can associate any exam with any user and also associate any answer with any user.

So for example if you submit a form to your `Answers` controller you could then create associations that would track the previously selected answers for each user like so:

```
            answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
            user_answer = UserAnswer.create(answer_id: answer.id, user_id: user.id, question_id: answer.question.id)
```

So now you could do a rather joins with your `User`, `Exam`, and `UserAnswer` models to pull every answer a user gave for a specific exam. If you use your current model structure you could get there, but it won't be quite as scalable and you'll probably have to hack around to get some of it to work like you want.

Comment: The issue with an approach like this is that the production app has thousands of questions that already exist with our `MultipleChoiceQuestion`, so re-engineering it right now it not very feasible. This is a great suggestion though, but I'm looking for a way to work within the current constraints.